# How to store values from a field on excel

Tags: database, excel, input

this is the first time posting here for me.

I have a quick question about excel. Currently I have an input page where I can input a project name and then fill out details on the project. Is there a way that I can store this information on another sheet? For example, if I type in "Project A" in the project input, then that will be saved in another sheet in a table or something, and the proceeding information (like date, price, etc) will be saved along with it. Then, if I type a new project name in, like "Project B", a new entry will be created with subsequent data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ancient Excel data form seems to still exist, even in Excel 2013.

Create a data table with headings and at least one row of data. Select the range and hit Ctrl-T or Insert > Table. This will turn the range into an Excel table.

Now either create a custom group on a ribbon and add the following command to this or your Quick Access Toolbar: All Commands > Form...

Select a cell in the table and hit the Form button that you just inserted into the QAT or the ribbon and you will see a dialog where you can create new rows in the table, and you see a few other buttons to manage data in the table, including deleting rows and searching data in existing rows.

That is the easiest no-code approach.